# Python: groupwise & recursive computation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas data frame looks like this:

```
      id          obal            sprin  prepayment       obal_prepay
      1           100               10    0.02
      1           90                15    0.03
      1           75                20    0.04
        ...           ...        ...         ...
      2           150               10    0.02
      2           140               10    0.03
      2           120               20    0.04
```

I need to apply following group wise operations:

1. for every id-group, I need to add 1 row at the beginning which will contain one specific number of a different column.
2. for every id-group I have to do following "recurisve" calculation
   to get the "obal_prepay" values: 
   obal_prepay[i]=obal[i-1]-prepayment*[obal_prepay[i-1]-sprin[i]
   For one simple example in an numpy array the code would look like this:

   ```
      for i in range(1,len(id)):
       array[i,4]=array[i-1,0]-array[i-1,4]*array[i,3]- array[i,2]
   ```

The final data frame should look like this

```
 id          obal            sprin  prepayment       obal_prepay
  1           100                 -      -            100
  1           100               10    0.02            100-100*0.02-10=88
  1           90                15    0.03            100-88*0.03-15=82.36    
  1           75                20    0.04            90-82.36*0.04-20=...
    ...           ...        ...         ...
  2           150                -    -               150
  2           150               10    0.02            150-150*0.02-10=137
  2           140               10    0.03            .. .
  2           120               20    0.04            ..
```

Hope that was clear enough!

Thanks,

KS

Comment: It would greatly help if you were to create a smaller less complex set of sample data with the expected output.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I adjuted my question accordingly.

Comment: You may need a for loop here

Comment: maybe write an own function for-loop and call it with apply?

Comment: So I'm thinking of splitting my data set into grouped lists, which then would serve as an input for my loop-function..Is there a more efficient way of doing that?