# How to call a list of DataFrames in a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I grouped my df into different ids:

```
df = [x for _, x in fulldf.groupby('ids')]
```

Now I get a list object of different data frames, each has a different size.

I wrote an own function which uses each grouped data frame as an input:

```
def myfunction(df):      
    A[1:,0]=df.A      
    A[0,0]=df.A+df.B
```

How can I know iterate through the data frames of the list? F.e.:

```
myfunction(df's of the list)
```

How can I do that? I hope that was clear enough.

Thanks,

KS

PS: the question relates to question [Python: groupwise & recursive computation on pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835485/python-groupwise-recursive-computation-on-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment94519759_53835485) where one can find input & desired output.

Comment: Why aren't you using `groupby.apply`?

Comment: how about `[myfunction(x) for x in df]` ?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of your input and desired output?

Comment: I asked a similar question here already where one can find also the input & desireed output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835485/python-groupwise-recursive-computation-on-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment94519759_53835485

Comment: can't vouch about it's efficiency though, maybe the link from jpp tells you more about it!

Comment: @Yuca, No, my link is functionally equivalent to your suggestion. `groupby` + `apply` *may* be the best option here, but we need more information to confirm.

Comment: got it @jpp, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Yuca your first suggestion works perfectly. Not sure if it is the most efficient way but in a  list of +6800 df with sizes of [100+,15] it computed it in seconds! Many thanks!